# pgrep for processes which are not associated with a terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu, grep, tty, ps

I would like to find all of the IDs of processes which are not associated with a terminal.

When I do the `ps aux | less` command, I see in the TTY field a lot of processes with `?` character.

I would like to get those process IDs. Is there a way to do that with `pgrep`?

I tried looking at the documentation over [here](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pgrep&sektion=1), but it's not very clear to me.

Comment: What is meant by, not associated with a terminal ?

Answer (score 0):

## Using `find`

```
pgrep --inverse -t \
  "$(find /dev/ -type c -regex '.*tty[0-9]+' -printf '%f ')"
```

The `find` command is invoked through [command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03). Since the command substitution is enclosed in double quotes, the output is passed to `preg` as a single word.

Options:

- `-type c` selects only character special files (can be checked with `stat -c '%F' /dev/tty*`);
- `-regex '.*tty[0-9]+'` selects only files matching the regular expression, that is everything (`.*`) followed by one or more (`+`) digits (`[0-9]`);
- `-printf '%f '` prints filename followed by a space (`find` prints a trailing newline by default). Since `-t` option accepts a list of TTY names (without the `"/dev/"` prefix), separated with commas or blanks, we can put either space, or comma after the filename (`%f`).

## Using Filename Expansion

```
cd /dev
ttys=( tty[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]? )
cd - >/dev/null
pgrep -a --inverse -t "${ttys[*]}"
```

`tty[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?` is expanded to `tty` followed by one, two, or three digits (`?` makes the preceding pattern optional).

`ttys=( words )` builds an array from the [`IFS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator)-separated words (`IFS` is also known as "input field separator").

`"${ttys[*]}"` is expanded to a single word consisting of the array items separated with the first character from `IFS` (default is space).

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to find all of the IDs of processes which are not associated with a terminal.
>
> Is there a way to do that with `pgrep`?

No, but there's a way with [`ps`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/ps.1.html) and its options

- `a      … this option causes ps to list all processes with a terminal …`
- `-N     Select all processes except those that fulfill the specified conditions (negates
         the selection). …`
- `o format
         Specify user-defined format. …`

So, *to get those process IDs* only, with no header line:

```
ps a -N opid=
```